# Powershell enumerate sub objects from access database

Tags: powershell, object, ms-access

I am using powershell to work with data pulled from an access database, but I am having trouble pulling the data out of a multi-select field. The multiselect field can be 1 to many strings.

When I try to get the value of that field it just returns System.__ComObject. I've tried many things but I can't pull the values out of that field/object. $rs.Fields.Items("something").Value works for all the others fields I'm trying to extract. Ultimately, I'm trying to loop or foreach through them to add to a json object.

```
$rs.Fields.Items("Tactics").Value
```

returns

```
System.__ComObject
```

```
$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics") | get-member -MemberType Properties
```

returns these properties.

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{00001569-0000-0010-8000-00aa006d2ea4}

Name            MemberType Definition                               
----            ---------- ----------                               
ActualSize      Property   int ActualSize () {get}                  
Attributes      Property   int Attributes () {get} {set}            
DataFormat      Property   IUnknown DataFormat () {get} {set by ref}
DefinedSize     Property   int DefinedSize () {get} {set}           
Name            Property   string Name () {get}                     
NumericScale    Property   byte NumericScale () {get} {set}         
OriginalValue   Property   Variant OriginalValue () {get}           
Precision       Property   byte Precision () {get} {set}            
Properties      Property   Properties Properties () {get}           
Status          Property   int Status () {get}                      
Type            Property   DataTypeEnum Type () {get} {set}         
UnderlyingValue Property   Variant UnderlyingValue ()
```

Comment: Maybe check `$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics").psobject.properties` or even  `$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics").psobject.properties | Select-Object Name, Value` or  `$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics").Value.psobject.properties` ?

Comment: So `$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics").psobject.properties | Select-Object Name, Value` returns
`Name        Value             
----        -----             
Properties  System.__ComObject
ActualSize  12                
Attributes  122               
DefinedSize 4                 
Name        Tactics           
Type        9                 
Value       System.__ComObject
Precision   255               
NumericS... 255               
Original... System.__ComObject
Underlyi...                   
DataFormat                    
Status      0 `

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the property value is a collection. Have you tried iterating over `$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics")`, i.e.:

```bsh
$rs.Fields.Item("Tactics") | ForEach-Object { $_.OriginalValue }
```

Comment: Just outputs System.__ComObject.